# Replace table labels text on onload

Tags: jquery, replace, html-table, label, onload

I have a **table** in which I have to **replace** the **labels** of tables on load. Below is the **structure** of my table:

```
<table>
<tbody>



<tr>
<th>
<label for="id_first_name">Nombre:</label>
</th>
</tr>



<tr>
<th>
<label for="id_last_name">Apellido</label>
</th>
</tr>



<tr>
<th>
<label for="id_email">email</label>
</th>
</tr>



<tr>
<th>
<label for="id_password">njnjnj</label>
</th>
</tr>



</tbody>
</table>
```

like in this I need to replace

> Nombre

with

> Name

and other labels also

on load. Please suggest how can I do this.

Answer (score 3):

just use this code:

```
   $('document').ready(function(){
 $('tbody').find('label').text('name');

});
```

Comment: acctualy there are four different labels and i need to replace all of them

Comment: <table>
<tbody>



<tr>
<th>
<label for="id_first_name">Nombre:</label>
</th>
</tr>



<tr>
<th>
<label for="id_last_name">Apellido</label>
</th>
</tr>



<tr>
<th>
<label for="id_email">email</label>
</th>
</tr>



<tr>
<th>
<label for="id_password">njnjnj</label>
</th>
</tr>



</tbody>
</table>

Comment: i have uploaded the code at http://jsfiddle.net/TVLTp/ you can check it over there

Comment: sorry i cant give data attr because i am doing all this in django and the form is comming from forms .py   i have to replace the text by finding in the page

Comment: then try replacing 'data' attr with 'for'

Answer (score 2):

You can place your code to replace your label's text on `.ready()` and it will execute once the page is loaded.
Like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('label').text('Name');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(window).load(function() {
      $('label').text('Name');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i have fix this by using the code on below link

http://magentocodes.blogspot.in/